# OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR on MSYS2-based Windows github CI

Tags: cmake, github-actions, raylib

I'm trying to compile my project (based on raylib) using github CI.  I'm using MSYS2 with Windows to do this.  I've recently transitioned from a Makefile to cmake, and the CI continually fails with the following message.

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
/d/a/its_raining/its_raining/includes/raylib/src/OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR
```

This is identical to a message I received on an Ubuntu instance, and I solved that by installing `libgl1-mesa-dev`.  I've tried installing several different things for the Windows environment, but I continue to get the same error.

(Weirdly enough, the old Makefile "just worked".)

I've installed the following mess of packages, without success:

```
mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-mesa
mingw-w64-x86_64-mesa
mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-glew
mingw-w64-x86_64-glew
mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-freeglut
mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-glfw
```

Can someone please advise on what I need to do to allow the cmake to proceed?

Thanks